# Create column name based on value without execute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to create a column name based on the value of other columns. I need to return a value from a column, but the specific name depends on the value insert on other table.

From intance:

Table A

```
Column1 | Column2
1         2
```

Base on that values I need to go to the table B to the column "VE12".

I need this dynamiclly, so the execute(@query) is my last option and I would like to avoid CASE WHEN statments because I have more than 50 options.

My query will be something like:

```
select case when fn.tab=8 and fo.pais=3 then cp.ve83 end 
FROM fn
INNER JOIN fo ON fo.stamp = fn.stamp
INNER JOIN cp
```

If the value in the column tab is 8 and the value in column pais is 3 I should return the value in column ve83.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Could you prvoide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Hi D-Shih, I change the question it more information.

Comment: You need to use *dynamic SQL*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only sensible option is to go back to the business meaning of the data and redesign the database according to that, instead of according to "technique-oriented abstractions" such as these that SQL was never intended to support.

The main reason for this is that SQL was founded on *FIRST* order logic, and this precludes supporting stuff like varying domains.  Which you are doing (or at least seeking to do) because ve12 could be a DATETIME and ve83 could be a VARCHAR and ve56 coulb be a BLOB etc. etc.  So there is just no way for you [or anyone else] to determine the data type of the results in your query, and it is even more impossible to attach *meaning* to what comes out of your desired query precisely because of this varying-domain and varying-source characteristic.